Turning Tourist visa into student visa (Germany)
For admission into bachelors programs in Germany, often third world nationals have to first attend a prep course. One can only enter this prep course through clearance of an exam. Typically one applies for a student applicant visa to write the exam.
One of my friend applied for the student visa and didn't get it in time. Hence, they applied also for a tourist visa, wrote the exam and are one month into the course.
The question is, can she turn the tourist visa into a study one or must she go back and reapply?
Country of origin: Belaruss

Impossible to say without actual data. For example, what country are they from?

If she is "one month into the course" and doesn't have a study visa she is probably already violating the terms of the visa she does have. Maybe. Depends on exact nature of the course. But if she is then this is bad, and may ell prevent her getting a study visa in any way.

Visa nationals have no right to convert a German ‘C’ visa into a residence permit to stay because of education, training, or economic reasons.
Source: https://www.germany-visa.org/immigration/residence-permit/converting-schengen-visa-into-residence-permit/
