Reapplying for family reunion visa after entering Germany on a tourist visa with family reunion with pending status in home embassy
My friend (18, Belarussian) applied to a family reunion visa. Intandem with being with her parents, she also wanted to pursue studies in Germany.  For 5 months there was no response from the Embassy. Since she didn't want to miss her entrance exams, she took a tourist visa, came here, wrote it and passed. Now, she is in the course since some months.
She tried contacting the Auslanderbehörde where her parent lives (Thuringana), however they didn't give clear responses and neither do they answer calls.
She, at the moment, lives in another state, so I would like to ask would it be possible to apply for the family reunion visa from inside the country at the auslanderbehörde?

Since they're actually illegally staying in Germany (unless they have a student D visa), even if it was possible I would be sceptical of the prospect of any application succeeding

Related question from the OP https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/27180/turning-tourist-visa-into-student-visa-germany
